# Refresh a particular tab using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, tabs, refresh, actionbarsherlock

I have several tabs with ActionBarSherlock and I want to refresh a particular tab when that tab is in view.

I just don't know what code I'm suppose to include on my onOptionsItemSelected.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the current code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        toggle();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_search:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem()==1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "refresh tab2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Code would go here I suppose...  


        } 


    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To re-draw a view, you can use its .invalidate(); method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

While I'm sure you're aware if you're using ABS, grab the view which is visible using findviewbyID()